# Magnetic Field in Perfect Electric Conductor

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

I know that one of Maxwell's equations states that the curl of the electric field is proportional to the time derivative of the magnetic field. We know that the electric field in a perfect electric conductor is 0, so why couldn't the magnetic field just be a constant instead of 0?

Edit: There is no current everywhere in space.

Comment: Total magnetic field *can* be non zero in perfect conductor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maxwell's equations give us the divergence and the curl of the magnetic field in this case:

$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B}=0$$

$$\nabla\times\mathbf{B}=\mu_0\mathbf{J}$$

For a conductor with current flowing, there is obviously a nonzero, non-constant (in space) magnetic field with a finite curl. I gather that this is not the situation you asked about, since you asked specifically about differentiating between zero field and a *constant* field (i.e. constant in space). In this particular case, we have a conductor with no current flowing, which means:

$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B}=0$$
$$\nabla\times\mathbf{B}=0$$

There is a very important theorem in vector calculus (commonly called the *Helmholtz theorem*) that, in a particular formulation, states:

> Any field that vanishes at infinity is **uniquely** determined by its divergence and curl.

In other words, if we find a field with zero divergence and curl everywhere that also vanishes at infinity, then we have found **the only** field with these properties.

Here's the important part: **for any finite conductor, we expect the magnetic field to vanish at infinity**. So we need a field that has zero divergence and zero curl everywhere which also vanishes at infinity. It turns out that $\mathbf{B}=0$ is exactly such a field, and by the theorem above, it is **the only** field configuration which can describe this situation.

The other important part: **any infinite conductor is constructed as a limit of progressively larger finite conductors**. Since the field is zero everywhere for all of the finite conductors, it's natural to choose the field to be zero everywhere for infinite conductors as well.

Comment: Why do you assume current is zero everywhere?

Comment: @JánLalinský I guess I figured it was implicit in the question for some reason. I'll revise.

Comment: @probaby_someone Yes I was thinking of a system with no current flowing. The uniqueness stated in the theorem answered my question. Thanks.

Comment: @probably_someone I am studying the quantization of the radiation field in the cavity of a resonator. During the derivation, they stated that the tangential surface component of the electric field is 0, and the normal surface component of the magnetic field is 0. But the derivation allows for non-zero tangential surface component of the magnetic field. So why does the normal component of the magnetic field at the surface always equal to 0?

Comment: @probably_somone Ok nevermind I get. The B field in the perfect electrical conducting material is 0 if there is no current to start with. And we know that the normal component of the magnetic field is continuous across the surface. So the only magnetic field left at the inner surface is the contribution by the tangential component from the EM wave.